# If one was to remove their Facebook account that has registered Facebook apps will they be deleted?

Tags: facebook

If one was to remove their Facebook account and "Deactivate" it, would the registered Facebook apps be deleted too? I would like to remove my account but still use the Facebook APIs in my applications. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to deactivate if you're the only admin of an app - you'll need to add additional admins before you can deactivate

Comment: It is possible, but the application gets deleted.

Comment: You may be right, certainly apps with no owner are disabled, but i thought there was a protection against people disabling their own account if that was the case - i've never deactivated.
What i said is definitely true for disabling Platform - you must delegate control of the apps before you can remove the Developer app and deactivate Platform